# SmsManager sending message more than one

Tags: java, android, sms

I am developing an auto reply android application which will send messages to the incoming number, if it matches with the selected number i.e. saved in the database. It running successfully but it send message twice some time, it sends three messages to that incoming number.

I am using the following code:

```
void processCall(String inNumber, String msg) {

    try {

        String sent = "android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT";
        PendingIntent pisent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0, new Intent(sent), 0);
        PendingIntent pidel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0, new Intent("Dilivered"), 0);
        SmsManager man = SmsManager.getDefault();

        //ArrayList<String> smstext = man.divideMessage(msg);
        man.sendTextMessage(inNumber, null, msg, pisent, null);
        //man.sendMultipartTextMessage(inNumber, null, smstext, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," msg send successfully to " + inNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ContentValues sentSms = new ContentValues();
        sentSms.put(TELEPHON_NUMBER_FIELD_NAME, inNumber);
        sentSms.put(MESSAGE_BODY_FIELD_NAME, msg);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        contentResolver.insert(SENT_MSGS_CONTET_PROVIDER, sentSms);
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where i do wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is on the method firing this one... Can you add the code?

Comment: String originalNumber = incomingNumber.substring(incomingNumber.length()- 5,incomingNumber.length());

Comment: if (originalNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(savenumstr.substring(savenumstr.length()- 5,savenumstr.length()))) {
        // if(incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(savenumstr)){
         
        try {
         TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) MyPhoneStateListener.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         Class c1 = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
Method m = c1.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
         ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony) m.invoke(manager);
telephony.endCall();
processCall(incomingNumber, message);
}

Comment: You can edit your message to add the code so its easier readable! And still it is not clear what action triggers the double sms send. Are you using a Broadcast receiver or any Observer to DB? Are there always more than one sms? The code you are using in the second comment is inappropriate by the documentations!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in Log messages in between and see how many times this function is getting executed. Also, if this is a service running, see if you are firing the service multiple times